# Dumpbin warning LNK4195: unable to load msdis170.dll

Tags: windows, sdk, disassembly, dumpbin

I'm trying to use `dumpbin` with the `/DISASM` option to dump the disassembly of a file.
It gives me the error `LINK : warning LNK4195: unable to load msdis170.dll`.

Apparently the file `msdis170.dll` doesn't exist on my computer.
I've tried reinstalling the Windows SDK and that didn't work.
So, how do I get this file?

I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, with the latest version of the Windows SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you are missing `msdis170.dll` from your PATH.  Look for it on your drive and add the directory it resides in to your PATH.

```
set PATH=%PATH%;<directory_where_DLL_resides>
dumpbin /disasm <file_to_disassemble>
```

UPDATE:
  What version of the SDK do you have?  You said latest, but what version?  I know that WinSDK 7.0/7.1 comes with `msdis160.dll`.  Where did you get your version of `dumpbin.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by install Visual C++ Express Edition.

<sub><sup>(posted as an answer on behalf of asker)</sup></sub>